# Replace New Lines in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create a script to filter through a lot of lyric files. Here's the code I have:

### Node.js

```js
fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf-8', (err, data)=>{
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return
    }
    data = data.replace(/\n[0-9]\n/, "Verse " + /\n[0-9]\n/)
    console.log(data)
    fs.writeFile(path.join(newDir, file), data, ()=>{
        console.log(file)
    })
})
```

### Original Text File

```
Title

1
Some lyrics

2
Some lyrics
```

### What the new text file SHOULD look like

```
Title

Verse 1
Some lyrics

Verse 2
Some lyrics
```

It can't seem to find the `\n (newline), a verse number, \n (newline)`. Also, obvious problem I'm not sure how to fix, the third parameter in `.replace()` probably isn't the same as the first parameter. Can anyone guide me on how could I filter through these?

Comment: attach a sample file, you are parsing ..

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad Literally what I did under the JavaScript file.

Comment: please upload a text file you are parsing, don't paste here.. upload as file..

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad Not sure how to upload a file to Stack Overflow, but you could just take the "Original Text File" and put it in any .txt file.

Comment: can't figure out what are you trying to do. Are you trying to get "Original Text File" to be formatted like "New Text File"?

Comment: @BARNI Yep, I'm trying to replace every `number` with `"Verse " + number`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect there is a `\r` prior to the `\n`. But you don't want to specify `\n` (or `\r\n` or `\r?\n`) anyway; use the multiline flag (`m`) and `^` and `$` assertions. (You also need the `g` flag if you want to do more than just the first match.)

> Also, obvious problem I'm not sure how to fix, the third parameter in .replace() probably isn't the same as the first parameter.

The second, not third (it doesn't take a third). To use what you matched in the string, you can use `$&` (or pass in a function and use the first argument it receives). Details in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) (or, of course, [the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-string.prototype.replace)).

With `m`, `g`, and the assertions:

```
data = data.replace(/^[0-9]$/gm, "Verse $&");
```

Live Example:

```js
let data =
    "Title\r\n" +
    "\r\n" +
    "1\r\n" +
    "Some lyrics\r\n" +
    "\r\n" +
    "2\r\n" +
    "Some lyrics\r\n";

data = data.replace(/^[0-9]$/gm, "Verse $&");

console.log(data);
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm, saved me manually changing 700 text files

Answer (score -1):

You can make sure `replace` method 2nd argument `replacement function`.  Following is example usage.

```js
let data = "1";
data = data.replace(/([0-9])/, match => "Verse " + match);

console.log(data)
```